# Connect to localhost failed using Mail::Sendmail module on Windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, email, windows-10

I have the following code:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -w

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mail::Sendmail;

sendmail(
    From    => 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com',
    To      => 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com',
    Subject => 'test email',
    Message => "body of the message",
);
```

I get the following error:

> Connect to localhost failed (An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.) no (more) retries!

I'm not sure how to correct it, any idea? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @Dave I think they mean they run the program on Windows 10, not that it works on Windows 10.

Comment: There's no point in putting a shebang `#!` line on your Perl code except to apply command-line switches. The Windows command processor ignores it, and uses the file extension instead to determine what program to use to execute your code. Since you have `use warnings`, there's no need fir `-w` as well and you can delete that first line altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Your local system isn't offering an SMTP service

You need to specify an SMTP server by specifying the host name in the `smtp` parameter of your call to `sendmail`